# How do you edit a part's symbol in Fritzing?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, fritzing

How do you edit the circuit symbol and pcb shape of a part in Fritzing?

I want to edit a "1x6 SMD header" part to only have 3 pins, so I effectively just need to "chop off" half the part.

If I right-click on the 1x6 part and select "Edit", it opens the part editor, but the editor doesn't appear to let me edit much. The only thing I seem to be able to do is delete pads and tweak some meta data, but the overall shape of the part is read-only.

All the tutorials and guides I've found through Google describe how to create a part from scratch, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Fritzing is a very crude, practically useless program that should simply be avoided. There is nothing to gain by using it instead of a real design package like Eagle or KiCAD. It has minimal functionality, is downright ugly, and cannot convey the information required to do much of anything with it. My recommendation is to learn how to use Eagle. Avoid Fritzing like the plague.

Comment: @DerStrom8, Having used both Fritzing and Eagle, I couldn't disagree more. Fritzing's incomplete part editor aside, I was able to design pcb's in Fritzing in under 5 minutes. Comparatively, I've been reading tutorials on how to use Eagle, and after weeks, I still can't figure out how to use it for any real work. I realize you're probably very experienced with Eagle, and are used to all its flaws, but it's a terrible tool which is nearly unusable, especially for beginners like myself. I'm not going to spend a month learning to do in Eagle what took me seconds to learn in Fritzing.

Comment: @DerStrom8, And responses like yours are not very helpful. You irrationally hate Fritzing and that's fine, but many like it and want to get further help with it. The fact is that Fritzing wouldn't exist if Eagle were a good tool. If you can't provide help with Fritzing, please don't troll stackexchange.

Comment: 1) Speed is only a nicety in PCB design, and its importance is greatly overshadowed by having the ability to create clean, accurate, and readable full-featured designs that anyone with any electronics experience can follow. Fritzing has none of these. 2) Calling a tool "terrible" simply because you're having trouble learning how to use it is immature and irrational. I was a beginner when I first started using it and it was not at all unusable, you simply had to stick with it.

Comment: 3) My hatred of Fritzing is not remotely irrational and is shared by countless others, not only here at EESE but also in the professional and hobbyist electronics field. 4) Once again, claiming that Eagle isn't a "good tool" just because you can't seem to learn it is ridiculous, and only makes you look like an idiot.

Comment: 5) My comment *is* helpful, though you have simply decided to ignore my advice. Think of it this way: You're standing on a cliff and you want to jump. I tell you not to but you argue that it's the fastest way to the bottom. Is my advice not helpful simply because you choose to ignore it? 6) Fritzing is a toy, nothing more, and it shouldn't even be used as a toy. It's a complete piece of garbage that won't get you anywhere in the real world. Take my advice or don't, I don't care, you're only hurting yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it isn't about grown up engineering at all.

Comment: @Andyaka You should probably start with your own comment then. Please try and act like an adult.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I'm sorry if I disparaged your preferred tool, but I wasn't trying to be insulting. A lot of people dislike Eagle, owning to its Windows 95 era UI and steep learning curve. Downvoting a question while leaving snarky comments instead of a real answer is immature and irrational. Your points about Fritzing are all just projections of your own insecurities and inexperience with it, and I suspect you've used it less than I've used Eagle, which is ironic since you're charging with not taking the time to learn something.

Comment: @Cerin FYI the downvote is not because you're trying to use Fritzing, it's because of your constant rude and abusive attitude towards other members (not just myself -- I couldn't care less what you think of me) and your ignorant and arrogant behavior.

Comment: @DerStrom8, I apologize if my tone came off as rude, but how am *I* the one being abusive and arrogant? I'm not the one downvoting you for reasons unrelated to the question. I'm not the one calling you ignorant for disagreeing with me. I'm not the one saying you're not an "adult engineer" because you're not using my preferred tools.

Comment: @DerStrom8, I concede that Fritzing doesn't have the same maturity of features as many other tools, but that's not relevant to my original question. When someone posts a question about Arduino, do you insult them for not using a more advanced microcontroller? This thread has gone off-topic, so I'll end it here, and again apologize if my tone contributed to any animus.

Comment: @Cerin This will be my last comment as well. You need to re-read my previous comments. Once again I am not downvoting you for wanting to use Fritzing, I am downvoting you for attacking other members, especially ones who were simply trying to offer a recommendation. Also, Eagle is by far not my preferred tool, I am stating that it is not a terrible tool simply because you don't know how to use it. I am stating that Fritzing *is* a terrible tool because 1) it does not have the features required for a neat design, and...

Comment: 2) Fritzing is a terrible way to convey information to actual engineers and board manufacturers. My first comment was recommending that you use an actual tool that *can* convey the information properly so that you can get better assistance. It's not a matter of "you're not an adult engineer because you're not using my preferred tools", it's a matter of "this tool is not sufficient to convey information required to get proper help". You seem to have missed the entire point of these posts. And your tone definitely came across as rude and arrogant, so that is what you have received in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I knew Fritzing does not have a fully functioning parts editor. However, if you go into the parts folder and adjust the .xml files you should be able to change the part layout and the icon in the parts bank (right-hand side) should update to the PCB layout version. You can edit the parts in an SVG editor, Inkscape is a great option.

Here is a short video that shows how to build custom parts. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blKyNYp8z3E&list=PLzwZMxf18zdPa4SMvj2BeN0yzDzHt1ta6

It is not creating a part for scratch, but rather editing a part down to what you need.